# Energy for 1-D wavelet in Python

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet, energy

I was wondering if there is an implementation for the Energy for 1-D wavelet in Python, the same as the Matlab '[Ea,Ed] = wenergy(C,L) '.
I have tried to write one on my own but i am not sure of it:
The formula is:

[image]

Where Dj is supposed the detail vector, and j = 1,2,...,ld and N1 is the data length at the decomposition level.

```
import json
import pywt
f=open('DataFile.txt','r')
D=json.load(f)
f.close()
#create the wavelet function
db1 = pywt.Wavelet('db13')
#calculate the number of necessary decompositions
NbrDecomp= pywt.dwt_max_level(len(D), db1)+1
#Initialize an empty list to receive the Detail and Approximation
Vector = [None] * NbrDecomp
#we use the Wavelet decomposition in the pywt module 
Vector = pywt.wavedec(D, db1)
#Now Vector = [Approxiamtion N, Details N, Details N-1,.....] 
#Where N would be the number of decompositions
```

According to the definition the energy at the level k is :

```
Energy(k)=np.sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in Vecktor[len(Vektor)-N-1-k]])/len(Vektor))
```

Was the implementation correct ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using NumPy's square root when the stock `sqrt` function from the `math` package in Python will do?  None of your datatypes were originally` numpy` arrays so I don't see a point in computing an output `numpy` array (at least not in this current version of the code) when you will probably not take advantage of `numpy`'s data representation.

Comment: Your double `Vector` definition is superfluous, you cannot preallocate a list and overwrite it entirely.

Comment: Remove the square root term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a little bit:

```
coeffs[len(coeffs) - k - 1]
```

can be rewritten as

```
coeffs[-k]
```

and you can do the squaring and summation as one NumPy operation (since you're using NumPy already)

```
def Energy(coeffs, k):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.array(coeffs[-k]) ** 2)) / len(coeffs[-k])
```